# Where about should my main class be created in a project?

Tags: java, swing, object

The problem is where a class should be created in my code. An example is I have a UI class and a main logic class that controls other objects.

Should the main logic class create the UI object, or should the UI object create the instance of the main logic class?

An explanation of which method is best and why would be ideal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

I think controller classes should instantiate the UI.

Whether you have a driver that contains the main, or the controller owns it, is immaterial.

If you change UI, your app should still work fine.  Don't put the main in the UI classes.

Comment: This is the way I prefer too. IMO, having one controller class to instantiate the UI is the cleaner method.